# NavigationView introduces white space at top of screen

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigationbar, navigationview

Introducing NavigationView seems to inject white space at the top of the screen.

[image]

Without it the text sits at the top.

[image]

The code is basic:

```
 var body: some View{
    NavigationView{
        VStack {
            Text("Top Title")
        ...
        Spacer()
```

In previous versions of iOS there used to be a command:

```
.navigationBarHidden(true)
```

but there doesn't seem to be a current equivalent. A lot of the workarounds on SO seem to steer towards removing the NavigationView. I'm using a tabBar so need it.
What's your advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (you might need to specify `for:` in some cases):

```
.toolbar(.hidden)
```

Comment: YES! I put it at the end of the VStack and not with the .NavigationBar controls at the level after.